# What's the etymology of push_back in C++?

Tags: c++, history, stdvector

What's the rationale for the `push_back` method name in C++ `std::vector`? For instance, is there a stack-based origin (`push` being a common stack operation)? Was there a pre-existing library that used these terms for adding to a sequence?

Besides common terms other APIs use like `append` and `add`, `insert_end` would seem to be more internally self-consistent (though `front` and `back` do exist elsewhere).

Comment: std::vector has `push_front`?

Comment: What would you call `pop_back` if you used `append` for `push_back`? `depend`?

Comment: Thanks @Jesse. I have to think of push_front to remember how to parse push_back, and forgot push_front is not in vector. Removed push_front from the Q.

Comment: @Martinho, some use unadorned `push` and `pop`; some use `add`/`remove(n-1)`. Qt::QList uses `append`/`prepend`, `removeFirst`/`removeLast`.

Comment: add() doesn't have enough underscores to make it sound useful enough.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes the opposite of `append` is `prepend`, not `depend`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you mention, `push` and `pop` are common names for stack operations. The reason it's not just `push` and `pop` is so that it can be consistent with the other containers. `std::vector` only implements `push_back` and `pop_back`, but there is also `push_front` and `pop_front` in, for example, `std::list`. Having consistent names is useful when writing generic functions.

Comment: +1 for the *consistent names* be it generic functions or programmers brain, consistent naming is good.

Comment: I was really more interested in why the push and pop part for a vector (or a list), but I didn't ask well.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that it's due to those methods facilitating the use of `std::vector` as a stack---if all you do is `push_front(foo)` and `pop_front()` (or the back equivalent), you've got a stack.

Comment: `std::vector` does not have `push_front` and `pop_front` operations (the committee settled on simplicity, it would have been possible efficiently using a 4th member)